# Multiline pattern after pattern match using sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a config file that consists of multiple sections and lots of them contain a property with the same name, let it be `host`. I need to replace the `host` property of one particular section only. Here's the file:

```
section1 {
  ...
  setting1 = "true"
  ...
  host = "localhost"
  ...
}
section2 {
  ...
  host = "whatever"
  ...
}
```

I want to replace the `host` value of `section2` with something else. Note that there may be any number of lines in between, marked as `...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak '/^section2 {/,/^}/s/host .*/host = "newvalue"/' file
```

This will search between `section2 {` and the next `}`, changing all `host =` occurences. GNU sed syntax, you should use eg `sed -i '' ...` on OSX.

Comment: I also had to add `-i`, but yes, this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n}"}
  /section2/{sub("host =[^\n]*", "host = \"newvalue\"")}NF' file 

section1 {
  ...
  setting1 = "true"
  ...
  host = "localhost"
  ...
}
section2 {
  ...
  host = "newvalue"
  ...
}
```

define the record structure, find the corresponding record and substitute.

Comment: Promising, but (a) it prints an extra `\n}` at the end, because the trailing `\n` is interpreted as an (empty) last record, and (b) it replaces everything starting with `host =` _through the end of the record_, potentially wiping out other keys. Requires GNU Awk or Mawk due to use of a multi-character `RS`.

Comment: yes, thanks, I didn't notice it before, extra brace need to be deleted.  I guess your second comment should be OK based on the file layout.

Comment: Thanks for updating (a shorter option would be to replace `1` with `NF` (`NF > 0`)); re 2nd comment: the OP says "Note that there may be any number of lines in between, marked as `...`", so I think it's fair to assume that lines after the `host` line _do_ need to be preserved.

Comment: yes, right, I guess my excuse is it's Friday afternoon.  Regarding `NF`, it will eliminate blank lines too, might not be welcome.

Comment: `NF` won't eliminate blank lines, only blank records and I don't see how that'd be possible with this format of input file, assuming there will never be a `}` without at least a preceding `{`.

Comment: right too, Friday afternoon is my excuse and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: The Friday afternoon slump continues, I'm afraid: `.*\n` is still too greedy; you need `[^\n]*`.

Comment: There comes a time in a Friday afternoon when the only good solution is two pints of lager and a packet of crisps :-).

Answer (score 0):

[Joao Morais's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657441/45375) is probably the best choice.

To complement it with an `awk` solution (a corrected, more robust version of [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657973/45375)):

- With ***GNU* `awk`**: <sup>Thanks, [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)</sup>

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ RS=ORS="}\n" }
  /^section2/ { $0 =gensub(/(\n *host = )[^\n]*/, "\\1\"new value\"", 1) }
  1' file
```

- **With `mawk`** (less robust; also works with GNU `awk`):

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ RS=ORS="}\n" }
  /^section2/ { sub(/ host = [^\n]*/, " host = \"new value\"") }
  1' file
```

<sup>Note: Due to use of a multi-character `RS` value, neither solution works with BSD/OSX `awk`; making it work there would require more effort.</sup>

**Explanation:**

- `RS=ORS="}\n"` tells `awk` to split the input into records by `}\n` instances (via special variable `RS`, the input record separator), and to use the same separator for output (via `ORS`, the output record separator).
- `/^section2/` matches literal `section` at the *beginning* of each record.

  - Mawk solution: `{ sub(/ host = [^\n]*/, " host = \"new value\"") }` replaces the value for key `host` with the new value.

    - Note the need to match only to the next newline `([^\n]*)`, because just `.*` would match to the end of the *record*, across line breaks.
    - It would be preferable to match the `host` key more robustly, such as with
      `sub("/(\n *host = )...`), but you'd need capture-group references to retain the same amount of preceding whitespace in the replacement value, which `sub()` doesn't support.
      *GNU* `awk`, however, does offer capture-group references via its nonstandard `gensub()` function; see below.
  - GNU Awk solution: Use of the nonstandard `gensub()` function enables the use of capture groups (`\\1` refers to the 1st captured group, ...), which makes the replacement both more robust and more convenient.

    - `gensub()`, unlike `sub()` doesn't modify the input string and instead *returns* the modified copy - hence the need to assign it to `$0`.
    - `1` as the 3rd argument tells `gensub()` to only replace *1* occurrence.
- `1` is a common shorthand for simply printing the resulting record.

Comment: Thanks, @EdMorton; I've restructured the answer and included a (modified version of) your command.